# Linear Discriminant Analysis(LDA) - Covariance matrix issue

Tags: algorithm, matrix, covariance, lda

I am trying to follow this you this video LDA example :
[LDA video example from Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kd3Xe0qWTvI&t=6s)

On 7th minute if video formula to calculate  co-variance matrix is given , and direct output of co-variance matrix is given as without explaining the mathematical steps:

```
 [[1/3 1/6],[1/6 1/3]]
```

I tried to solve the maths manually and my problem is if i calculate

`(x- means(x)) * (x- means(x))transpose`

i don't get the result. But instead if i use

```
(x- means(x))transpose * (x- means(x))
```

I get accurate result.

Please explain what is right formula because everywhere it is written as 
`(x- means(x)) * (x- means(x))transpose`

**But Matrix multiplication is NOT commutative .i.e.  It  is NOT true  that AB=BA**

`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math problem. Please post at [math.se].

Comment: It is a matter of convention. If your `x` is a column vector, you use the first formulation. If it is a row vector, you use the second one. One gives you a matrix (outer product), the other gives you a scalar (inner product).

Comment: thanks for help.. You you mentioned is right